# Copying files between two similar, but not matching, directory trees

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, directory-structure

I have a `source` directory structure and a `destination` directory structure. The `destination` directory structure is a sub-set of the `source` directory structure. That is, in the `destination` directory structure certain sub-folders are not present.

I want to copy certain files, lets say `*.jpg`, from the `source` to the `destination` and I don't want to create the missing folders at the `destination`. I think, for this reason I cannot use `robocopy` or `xcopy` as they would re-create the source-structure at destination when using the `/S /E` switches.

So the situation looks like:

```
source
  folder1
    subfolder1
      file1.jpg
  folder2
    file2.jpg
  folder3
    file3.jpg
```

```
destination (before copying)
  folder1
    subfolder1
  folder3
```

```
destination (after copying)
  folder1
    subfolder1
      file1.jpg
  folder3
    file3.jpg
```

I tried using something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set src_dir=l:\DP\
set dest_dir=l:\test

for /R "%src_dir%" %%x in (*.jpg) do (
    copy "%%x" "%dest_dir%\%%x"
)
```

I am pretty sure the problem is with `"%dest_dir%\%%x"` but no idea how to fix it. The English translation of the error message I get is  "The syntax for the file, directory or drive is wrong."

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Could you expand upon your question, to explain why you believe `Robocopy.exe` and `xcopy.exe` cannot be used for this, and where your existing code is, _(for us to help you to fix)_? Even using just the `copy` command, you must have at least tried something using `if exist`, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64661766/edit) to include a [mcve] of your code, and sufficient information for us to replicate the exhibited issue it causes. This site does not provide a code writing, a one to one tutoring, or a metasearch, service.

Comment: First of all you have not addresses the question, I asked. Secondly, based upon your latest edit, we still have no idea what is, or isn't, happening according to your expectations. We expect to see the actual resulting tree, any error messages, and an explanation of how the results do not meet with your expectaions. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64661766/edit) to include that debugging information, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but I did my best. I explained why I think robocopy or xcopy would not provide a solution to my problem. I attached the code I tried using. What is missing is the error message. All right I try to provide a translation for that too.

Comment: What if there is already a file in the destination? skip, overwrite or update?

Comment: The destination should be empty or does not contain files with jpg extension. Anyway, your code solved that problem too! The script works perfectly! Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no switch for `xcopy` or `robocopy` that prevents it from creating directories.

Anyway, here is a script that accomplishes your task in a flexible manner (see the `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=%~dp0source"      & rem // (full path to source directory)
set "_TARGET=%~dp0destination" & rem // (full path to target directory)
set "_MASKS=*.jpg"             & rem // (`|`-separated list of patterns)
set "_MODE=A"                  & rem // (see below for possible modes)
set "_DIRS="                   & rem // (if empty, do not create sub-direcories)

rem // Resolve mode setting:
if /I "%_MODE%"=="A" (           rem // (`A`ll, copy new, overwrite existing)
    set "OPT=/-Y"
) else if /I "%_MODE%"=="R" (    rem // (`R`enew, copy new, overwrite older)
    set "OPT=/D"
) else if /I "%_MODE%"=="N" (    rem // (`N`ew, copy new, maintain existing)
    set "OPT= "
) else if /I "%_MODE%"=="P" (    rem // (re`P`lace, skip new, overwrite existing)
    set "OPT=/U"
) else if /I "%_MODE%"=="U" (    rem // (`U`pdate, skip new, overwrite older)
    set "OPT=/D /U"
) else exit /B 1

rem // Ensure that target directory exists:
mkdir "%_TARGET%" 2> nul & pushd "%_TARGET%" && (
    rem // Change into source directory:
    pushd "%_SOURCE%" && (
        rem // Resolve list of file name patterns and loop through them:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "eol=| delims=" %%M in (^"!_MASKS:^|^=^
%= mandatory blank line, do not (re-)move! =%
!^"        ) do (
            if "!!"=="" endlocal
            rem // Loop through applicable file paths relative to source directory:
            for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%E in ('
                xcopy "%%~M" "%_TARGET%" /L /E /I %OPT:/U=% /Y
            ') do (
                set "FLAG=#" & if "%%F"=="" set "FLAG="
                rem // Check whether target sub-directory and file already exists:
                if not exist "%_TARGET%\%%F\.." (
                    if defined _DIRS (md "%_TARGET%\%%F\..") else set "FLAG="
                )
                if "%OPT%"==" " if exist "%_TARGET%\%%F" set "FLAG="
                if not "%OPT:/U=%"=="%OPT%" if not exist "%_TARGET%\%%F" set "FLAG="
                rem // Actually copy current file:
                if defined FLAG copy /Y "%%F" "%_TARGET%\%%F" > nul
            )
        )
        rem // Return from source directory:
        popd
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```